# Did Facebook recently disable accessing public page feeds via uri?

Tags: ios, facebook, feed, public

This worked in my iOS app just yesterday, it's worked for months. I wake up today and no bueno. I put this into the address bar of my web browser with the desired ID and now I'm getting "Sorry, this page isn't available." Anyone know what's up?

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=%@", pageId];
```

Answer (score 7):

same here i think there is a lot of people if you can find work around do tell please

Update

The Pages JSON feed (e.g. https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=%2019292868552&format=json) is now deprecated and will stop returning data from Jan 28, 2015 onwards. Developers should instead call the feed edge on the Graph API's Page object: /v2.2/{page_id}/feed.

Source

Though I can't find a way to access a feed without authentification ! Facebook is becoming more and more liberty killer and is withdrawing into himself !

Comment: Thanks for the response Shady. I was hoping to avoid authentication as well so as not to annoy the user. Oh well...