# Facebook public JSON or RSS feed

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, rss

So it seems that Facebook has deprecated the public JSON and XML feeds for profiles (https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=[id]).

I have a client's website that was grabbing a simple facebook feed for display on the homepage. They own the facebook page they want to feed from.

I understand I'm supposed to use the Graph API. But it doesn't seem possible without authentication. Is there any way to pull this data without generating a temporary token each time? Asking the user for facebook access every time they open this separate website seems like a really bad user experience.

This seems to be a recent deprecation on the part of facebook ([Did Facebook recently disable accessing public page feeds via uri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202262/did-facebook-recently-disable-accessing-public-page-feeds-via-uri)). Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use a page access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @WizKid, that helped! More specifically it looks like I needed to find a permanent page access token. This page had my answer: [facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token)

Answer (score 2):

For display public informations without authentifcation in Json, create a app to facebook graph.

You just need :

- Facebookappid
- Facebookappsecret
- Facebookpageid

And use this url :

> https://graph.facebook.com/Facebookpageid/feed?access_token=Facebookappid|Facebookappsecret

and Tada, you can see the public feed in Json.

Hope help someone.

Comment: No, no, no. Never include your app secret in user-accessible code!

Comment: @WackGet I agree but that is not the question.